Python: Insert escape character (single '\') into a string to escape markdown text rendering later
I'm hoping I'm overlooking something simple here. I have a function that sends some debug messages to Discord in code blocks (```). Since it can quote past messages, previous code blocks can interrupt the formatting of the new ones added by my function and break up the message into multiple code blocks at odd places, making it difficult to read.
I figured there would be a simple solution in just doing a:
msg.replace("```", "\```") 

but I am finding that isn't the case. It seems that if I either add 1 or 2 backslashes in the replacement text, python always seems to add two, such that discord displays one backslash and renders the code block rather than escaping the code block as intended. Two backslashes are also present when printing the string in console.
I have tried:
msg.replace("```", "\```") 
msg.replace("```", "\\```") 
re.sub("```", "\```", msg) 
re.sub("```", "\\```", msg)

All of these give the same result, which results in discord printing a backslash and then rendering the code block anyways.
How can I format the string such that it leaves a single escape character in the string before the code block tag?

try with  this "/'''"

Depending on how you print the string a single backslash will be shown as double backslashes: print('.\.') → .\. but print(['.\.']) → ['.\\.']

Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I did some googling, and I have the feeling the actual problem is that Discord simply doesn't support this.  Normally you'd escape three backticks (```) by fencing your code block with four backticks, four backticks with five, etc.  Discord doesn't seem to support this in my testing.  Post on Discord forums about it, Reddit suggestion to put NBSP between backticks.

I believe you have to do individual backslashes for every tick:"\\\\\"`

Hey, thanks for the responses. Forward slash doesn't escape the code block in discord, I think the only way is one single backslash before the backticks to escape the whole set.

Inserting a zero-width space as suggested in the Reddit link works well enough for me. Thanks Dale.

msg ="""
``` hello world
```
"""
msg = msg.replace("```","\```")

Replace method worked for me. I was able to escape the codeblock normally. I used the default IDLE IDE and python 3.9.1
Before escaping:

After escaping:

